# Iteratively convert an arbitrary depth list to a dict

Tags: python, algorithm, iteration

The input has a pattern, every element in the list is a dict and has a fixed keys

```py
[{'key': 'a', 'children': [{'key': 'a1', 'children': [{'key': 'a11', 'children': []}]}]}, {'key': 'b', 'children': [{'key': 'b1', 'children': [{'key': 'b11', 'children': []}]}]},]
```

expected output

```
{'a': {'a1': {'a11': ''}}, 'b': {'b1': {'b11': ''}}}
```

I want to do it in an iterative way, currently I'm able to get all the value of the fixed key `key`, but failed to compose to the targetd dict

```py
def get_res(stack, key='key'):
    result = []
    while stack:
        elem = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(elem, dict):
            for k, v in elem.items():
                if k == key:
                    # breakpoint()
                    result.append(v)
                stack.append(v)
        elif isinstance(elem, list):
            stack.extend(elem)
    print(result)
    return result
```

also stuck in recursive approach

```
def gen_x(stack):
    for bx in stack:
        if 'children' not in bx:
            return {bx['key']: ''}
        tem_ls = bx['children']
        xs = gen_x(tem_ls)
        print(xs)
```

Comment: Any specific reason you are not making use of the fact that children are under the `children` key?

Comment: Write the recursive version first; going from there to an iterative solution is a mechanical transformation. Right now the iterative junk is obfuscating your actual business logic.

Comment: Edit your question with your current recursive version, comments are no place for large snippets. Some observations: you only have one path through your function that returns anything. What about the other path? Secondly, looping over `enumerate(stack)` and then throwing away the first element again is pointless. Just write `for bx in stack: ...`.

Comment: Why the empty string for a leaf? Why not an empty dict?

Comment: @trincot need to add a customized object later, which were generated with other irrelevant omitted keys here,

Comment: @Botje I appreciate your question and advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a breadth-first traversal with a queue instead:

```
from collections import deque
from operator import itemgetter

def convert_tree(lst):
    tree = {}
    queue = deque([(lst, tree)])
    while queue:
        entries, branch = queue.popleft()
        for key, children in map(itemgetter('key', 'children'), entries):
            if children:
                queue.append((children, branch.setdefault(key, {})))
            else:
                branch[key] = ''
    return tree
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/hvfqLj

Answer (score 4):

The recursive approach is the natural choice here. You can use a [dict comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/) in your recursive function:

```
def to_dict(lst):
    if not lst:
        return ""
    return { obj["key"]: to_dict(obj["children"]) for obj in lst }
```

Call it like this:

```
lst = [{'key': 'a', 'children': [{'key': 'a1', 'children': [{'key': 'a11', 'children': []}]}]}, {'key': 'b', 'children': [{'key': 'b1', 'children': [{'key': 'b11', 'children': []}]}]},]

result = to_dict(lst)
```

It is a pity that you want the "leaf" nodes to have an empty string as value, which deviates from the fact that other values are always dicts. I would have assigned empty dicts instead, which seems more consistent, and the code for the function would then just consist of the comprehension expression:

```
def to_dict(lst):
    return { obj["key"]: to_dict(obj["children"]) for obj in lst }
```

If you really want to do this iteratively, you can use a depth-first traversal with an explicit stack:

```
def to_dict(lst):
    root = {}
    stack = [(root, lst)]
    while stack:
        node, lst = stack.pop()
        stack.extend((node.setdefault(item["key"], {}), item["children"]) 
                     for item in lst)
    return root
```